# Extension of derivations from coordinate ring of affine variety to local ring of the stalks

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety of $C^n$. $C$ is complex number. Let $D:A(X)\to C$ at a point $p\in X$ where $A(X)$ is coordinate ring and $D$ is a derivation. Let $m_p\subset A(X)$ be the maximal ideal corresponding to a point $p\in X$.

Derivation is basically a tangent vector of $T_pX$ if this $X$ is a complex manifold.

I wish to consider extension $D':A(X)_{m_p}\to C$ where $A(X)_{m_p}$ is inverting everything outside $m_p$ or the germ at the point $p\in X$. Clearly $D'|_{A(X)}=D$ where restriction means every element of the form $\frac{f}{1}$ where $f\in A(X)$.

Surely, I could extend $D$ by the standard derivation and show this extension is unique by $D$ acting on each $x_i$ of $A(A^n)$'s generators.

Q1. Why do I get this extension and this extension is unique?

Q2. Could I use some localization property here to say it exists and unique? Apparently for $g\not\in m_p, D'(\frac{1}{g})=-\frac{D'(g)}{g^2}$. There is no guarantee that $D'(g)\neq 0$. So I cannot conclude the image of $g$ under the map $D'$ is invertible. What kind of universal property should I use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f=\frac{a}{b}$. It's enough to show that $D'(f)$ can be calculated only using information from $D'|_{A(X)}=D$. It is clear that $D'(a)=D'(bf)=bD'(f)+fD'(b)$ by the definition of a derivation. But this implies that $D'(f)=\frac{1}{b}\left(D(a)-fD(b)\right)$, and everything on the RHS is defined in terms of data you already know - you know how $D$ acts on $a,b$ since $a,b\in A(X)_{m_p}$, and $f,\frac{1}{b}$ are both fixed. Therefore you have the result.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I thought. However, should not there be universal property for this?

Comment: Sure, there's probably a way to phrase it like that (look in Matsumura in the section talking about modules of differentials, I'd guess), but when it's this easy to write down, there's no harm in doing it this way. (Also, to verify that derivations satisfy the universal property, you would need to do something like the above answer!)

Comment: Yep. It seems Matsumura is the way to go. Thanks a lot.